# Creating a threshold function that works for all images

Tags: python, opencv

I am looking to determine an outer circle that bounds the shape, the edges of the shape, and the circle inside the shape.

To do this, I use this code for the threshold:

```
def adjustImage(img):
    src_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # src_gray = cv.fastNlMeansDenoising(src_gray, None, 10, 7, 21)
    _, thresh = cv.threshold(src_gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    thresh = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5, 5)))
    return thresh
```

However, this code doesn't always work depending on the image. How can I edit the threshold function with `adjustImage(img)` so it works for all images?

**Working example:**
[image: Ex 1]
[image: Ex2]
[image: Ex3]

**Non-working example:**
[image: Ex4]
[image: Ex5]
[image: Ex6]

Comment: Have you tried Otsu thresholding?

Comment: Why comment `fastNlMeansDenoising`? It does a good thing. Threshold worked fine on your "bad" image after it.

Comment: @fmw42, isn't it what he actually do?

Comment: Right. I though he was using adaptive thresholding. Perhaps he did at one time. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I tested this under **Matlab**, not Python, however, there's some `pseudo-code` you can use to port this to Python.

My suggestion:
Try using `adaptive thresholding` instead of simple threshold or Otsu’s thresholding. Of course, there's some parameters to fiddle with, however, you can get nice results.

This is the direct result of applying an `adaptive thresholding` your image:

[image]

Which in `Python`, should be fairly straightforward. Something like this:

```
grayImg = cv.imread( inputImage.png, 0 )
adaptiveBinary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold( grayImg, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
                                        cv.THRESH_BINARY, blockSize, C )
```

Fine tune the `blockSize` and `C` parameters as needed. In Matlab, the default adaptive method implemented is `Mean`.

The binary image is quite noisy, however, you can **filter** the small blobs using an area filter. Filter every blob that is below a `threshold value` (I used a value of `50`). Here's the output, showing the largest blob:

You will get something like this:

[image]

In Matlab this operation is just a line of code. In Python, the **area filter** could be implemented with something like this:

```
# Create a clone image to show the result
filteredImage = adaptiveBinary.copy()

# Find the bimary image contours: 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( adaptiveBinary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )

# Perform contour filtering:
for cnt in contours:
    # Filter if the contour area is small
    area = cv2.contourArea( cnt )
    if area < 50:
        continue
    # Draw the contour onto target image:
    cv2.drawContours( filteredImage [cnt], -1, (255, 255, 255), 2 )

    # Whatever additional processing you need to do

# Write output image:
cv2.imwrite( "filterResult.png", filteredImage )
```

Again, this is untested Python code, so, you will likely need to adjust/modify some things, but this is the general idea.